# dwx zeromq on MT5 for Mac

Tags: zeromq, mql4, mql5

I followed through an instruction from the github repository https://github.com/geekaia/mt5teste

I downloaded these files and I moved the dwx mq5 file into the Expert/Advisor folder in metatrader5 as expected, yet...I can't see the EA after refreshing

I use a Mac, and I was thinking if it makes any difference.

Although I had tried using the mq4 for metatrader4, it worked successfully but the mq5 file wouldn't work on metatrader5

Also, does anyone know which folders the remaining 3 "mqh" files should be moved to?

I'm stuck, would really appreciate any help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After many trials, I got a hang of it

The tested server codes are here for both mt4 and mt5

https://github.com/darwinex/dwxconnect

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.